# How to create new JSON data type using existing JSON data object in React-Typescript

Tags: reactjs, json, react-typescript

I have a type & need to create JSON data using below type.

```
export interface Test {
  name: string;
  address: Address;
  contactInformation: ContactInformation;
  status: string;
}
```

And I have a JSON Data

```json
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "status": "Active",
      "benefits": [
        {
          "type": "30",
          "Details": {
            "Network": [
              {
                "statusCode": "1",
                "contacts": [
                  {
                    "name": "Bla",
                    "address": {
                      "line1": "P.O. BOX 740800",
                      "city": "Bangalore",
                      "state": "Karnataka",
                      "stateCode": "KA",
                      "zipCode": "560001"
                    },
                    "contactInformation": [
                      {
                        "url": "WWW.Bla.COM"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to create new JSON data using above type. Below is the expected JSON data. I have tried using map in typescript and could not get desired output.

```json
{
  "NewData": [
    {
      "name": "Bla",
      "address": {
        "line1": "P.O. BOX 740800",
        "city": "Bangalore",
        "state": "Karnataka",
        "stateCode": "KA",
        "zipCode": "560001"
      },
      "contactInformation": [
        {
          "url": "WWW.Bla.COM"
        }
      ],
      "status": "Active"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to achieve?

Comment: No, It is status

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse`.

```
try {
    const object = JSON.parse(json);
} catch (err) {...}
```

Keep in mind that if you are receiving the JSON data over network, it should not be considered type-safe, so, use a library like [Joi](https://joi.dev/api/) to typecheck the object.

After making the object that you want to convert the incoming data to, use `JSON.stringify`.

EDIT: If your question is about how to create the object you want the incoming data to convert into, just this should work:

```
const result = {
  NewData: [
    {
      name: object.Data[0].benefits[0].Details.Network[0].contacts[0].name,
      address: {
        line1: object.Data[0].benefits[0].Details.Network[0].contacts[0].line1,
        city: object.Data[0].benefits[0].Details.Network[0].contacts[0].city,
        state: object.Data[0].benefits[0].Details.Network[0].contacts[0].state,
        stateCode: object.Data[0].benefits[0].Details.Network[0].contacts[0].address.stateCode,
        zipCode: object.Data[0].benefits[0].Details.Network[0].contacts[0].address.zipCode
      },
      contactInformation: [
        {
          url: object.Data[0].benefits[0].Details.Network[0].contacts[0].contactInformation[0].url
        }
      ],
      status: object.Data[0].status
    }
  ]
};
```

EDIT 2: With `.map`:

```
const result = {
    NewData: object.Data.map((x) => {
        return {
            name: x.benefits[0].Details.Network[0].contacts[0].name,
            address: {
                line1: x.benefits[0].Details.Network[0].contacts[0].line1,
                city: x.benefits[0].Details.Network[0].contacts[0].city,
                state: x.benefits[0].Details.Network[0].contacts[0].state,
                stateCode: x.benefits[0].Details.Network[0].contacts[0].address.stateCode,
                zipCode: x.benefits[0].Details.Network[0].contacts[0].address.zipCode
            },
            contactInformation: [
                {
                    url: x.benefits[0].Details.Network[0].contacts[0].contactInformation[0].url
                }
            ],
            status: x.status
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: If you are going to recommend a TS type validator, you also have [Zod](https://zod.dev/),  [Valibot](https://valibot.dev/), and [many others](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/a-typescript-runtime-data-validators-comparison-92887e22ee65) to choose from.

Comment: Zod is really great for TS, great recommendation. 

Comment: Any other logic by using .map in typescript?

Comment: If you mean having more elements in the `Data` array, then yes! You can use my solution in a `.map` function call.

Comment: I've modified the original solution to work with `.map` in the second edit.